# Keras not detecting GPU, but tensorflow is

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to get my keras back-end to work, but it keeps telling that there is no GPU, but my tensorflow say otherwise.

tensorflow

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Ouput

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 7600201089948511065
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 9640434864482537344
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 15836333527683385212
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

keras

```
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

Output

```
[]
```

Tensorflow-gpu works, but keras can't see for some reason

Cuda is installed

```
tensorflow-gpu = 1.14.0
keras = 2.0.8
python = 3.6
```

Comment: Are you using any conda/virtualenv environment? Can you check if there are any  global installations?

Comment: yes, but I currently install all package globally

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you tried uninstalling keras and installing keras-gpu? Are you using tf.keras to build and train models?

Comment: O I posted what i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things that you need to confirm before this,

Which GPU are you using? Only NVIDIA works.
Do you have tensorflow-gpu installed (keras uses this as its backend)?
Do you have CUDA installed?

Since tensorflow is detecting GPU, then its either an issue with on of the above points, or you may try upgrading the various packages.

Lastly, if nothing else works I would recommend using the high level API in tensorflow2 which is actually the same as keras.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using nvidia, tensorflow-gpu is installed

Comment: what about CUDA?

Answer (score 0):

Add ppa to ubuntu repos, they have the newest driver. Risky, but worth it!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Try to install newest cuda driver

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If this fails (like it did in my case), do sudo apt install for all dependencies it complains about.

In my case:

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-435 nvidia-dkms-435 nvidia-kernel-source-435
```

Tried again

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

reboot computer

Create a new conda env

```
conda create -n tf python=3.7

source activate tf


conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu tensorflow-gpu jupyter pytables pandas seaborn scikit-learn gensim -y
```